# Pushing configuration changes to an iOS app

Tags: ios, configuration, push

we have an app which gets its configuration from a portal. 
This is neither an **MDM Portal** nore any **MDM Functionality** is available in the app.

If the app starts for the first time, it contacts the portal and gets its initial configuration.

After this, it is polling the portal in a regular intervals to receive changes, if there is any.

I want to stop the polling. If there is a change, the Portal should **PUSH** it to its Apps. This can be done by Push Notifications, I can send some hint to the app, that there is new configuration to take it, but if the app does not run, the user can ignore this or according to the documentation, the PN is not a reliable system for vital information.

What could be the solution, did anyone have the same situation and solved it ?

Comment: You can use silent push notifications that are delivered to the app delegate and don't require any action by the user.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible for the user to switch off the "silent notifications" like the "push notifications" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the silent push notifications (using content-available APNS payload key).

Of course this is not guaranteed to be received so you should also implement some sort of data versioning / etag / date last updated mechanism which you poll when the app is opened in order to download the latest data manually if your silent notification was not received.